# Using predefined const strings

Tags: html

I'm using the following HTML code:

```html
<div class="p-col-fixed" style="width:150px">First line:</div>
```

For column alignment, I have to use `width:150px` in many places on the same HTML page.

How can I use a `#define`? In CSS?

Comment: Any reason to use inline styling as opposed to a class?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are comparing the scripting language with one of the programming languages that use the **#define** directive.
In CSS, we have class selector for that (in case you need to use that property on multiple places in the HTML.Class selectors are defined by placing a (.) dot before the name of the class selector and are used by specifing them as a value to the class attribute.
E.g.

> **CSS**
>
> ```
> .cust-width
> {
>     width:150px;
> }
> ```
>
> **HTML**
>
> ```
> <div class="p-col-fixed cust-width">First line:</div>
> ```

Another feature is the "id" which is used to further refine the selection and add additional properties to the selected class.IDs are generally used in cases when the change is required in fewer classes/tags.IDs are defined using (#) before the name of ID selector in CSS
E.g.

> **CSS**
>
> ```
> #cust-width
> {
>     width:150px;
> }
> ```
>
> **HTML**
>
> ```
> <div class="p-col-fixed" id="cust-width">First line:</div>
> ```

For your use-case, classes are ideal.Provided that change is required in multiple parts of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="p-col-fixed define">First line:</div>
```

css:

```
.define
{
    width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go in all that trouble? Simple solution is to create a CSS class and use it anywhere you need in your html file.

**CSS**

```
.width-150 {
   width: 150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="p-col-fixed width-150">First line: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in css and then add it in the div.

css file:

```
.width150 {
     width:150px;
}
```

Then, in your html file add the class

```
<div class="p-col-fixed width150 " >First line:</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **class**  if you want to add style to multiple elements.

Use **id** if you want to style only one element.

The best approach would be to add a class to the element first

Example : **custom-width**

HTML:

```
<div class="p-col-fixed custom-width">First line:</div>
```

CSS :

```
.custom-width
{
  width:150px;
}
```